Seeking Rigorous Resources on Proofs in Fractional Calculus (Riemann-Liouville Integral Continuity Proof)
Title: Seeking Rigorous Resources on Continuity Proofs in Fractional Calculus (Riemann-Liouville Integral Proof)
Body:
Hello everyone,
I’m currently studying fractional calculus and recently worked on a continuity proof for the fractional integral operator, specifically the Riemann-Liouville integral. My goal is twofold:

Get feedback on the correctness and rigor of my proof (detailed below).
Inquire about advanced resources or books that present similarly rigorous proofs of continuity and other core properties in fractional calculus.

Proof Outline:
In my proof, I aim to show the continuity of the Riemann-Liouville fractional integral $ I^\alpha f(t)$ over $[0, T]$ when $f$  is continuous. I applied a change of variables, setting $u = t \cdot v$, to simplify the integral as follows:

Start by expressing $I^\alpha f(t)$:
$$
   I^\alpha f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^t (t - u)^{\alpha - 1} f(u) \, du.
   $$

By substituting $ u = t \cdot v $, we rewrite the integral as:
$$
   I^\alpha f(t) = \frac{t^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^1 (1 - v)^{\alpha - 1} f(tv) \, dv.
   $$

Defining $ g(t, v) = (1 - v)^{\alpha - 1} f(tv) $, we have:
$$
   I^\alpha f(t) = \frac{t^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^1 g(t, v) \, dv.
   $$

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0, T]$, $g(t, v)$ is continuous for $ t \in [0, T] $ and $ v \in [0, 1) $. Also, $ |g(t, v)| \leq \|f\|_\infty (1 - v)^{\alpha - 1} $, and as $ (1 - v)^{\alpha - 1} \in L^1(0, 1) $ for $ \alpha - 1 > -1 $, we can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $ t \to \int_0^1 g(t, v) \, dv $ is continuous on $ [0, T] $.

Therefore, I conclude that $ t \to I^\alpha f(t) $ is continuous on $ (0, T] $.


My Questions:

Is the above proof rigorous and correct? Are there any improvements or additional justifications that could strengthen it?
Can you recommend any references—-books, lecture notes, or papers—that cover rigorous proofs and properties of fractional integrals, especially those using Lebesgue integration and variable changes?

Thank you in advance for any guidance on improving my proof and suggestions for resources!


After reading it carefully, I don’t see any flaw throughout your argument. I would only correct the conclusion in step 5, since the continuity follows at $t=0$ too.
With regard to books, standard references could be Fractional Integrals and Derivatives by Samko, Kilbas and Marichev, Theory and Applications of Fractional Differential Equations from Kilbas, Srivastava and Trujillo, Fractional Differential Equations by Podlubny, The Analysis of Fractional Differential Equations from Diethelm and An Introduction to The Fractional Calculus and Fractional Differential Equations from Miller and Ross.

